# How to cut out a piece of a stud fully from an existing wall?

Tags: tools, studs, cutting

I'm not sure what tool to use or how to use it to most effectively cut out a chunk of a stud of an existing wall that already has exterior wall sheathing on it.

[image]

Things I've considered:

1) **Circular Saw** - all safety stuff says to not cut on something that is mounted on both ends due to the likelihood of the blade pinching. Combine that with the fact that the blade depth can't penetrate fully through 3.5" widths of the board, the best I could hope for is a partial completion of the cut. Add to it that I'll be moving the blade sideways as opposed to blade pointed downward seems like even more of a case for me losing control.

2) **Reciprocating Saw** - maybe this could be used in combination with the circular saw to finish the partial depth cut, but there's not enough space between the other studs to get in there flush. And if cut at an angle, the blade will disappear into the stud being cut and could be cutting into and through the exterior sheathing without me seeing it.

3) **MultiTool** - This seems to be a possibility, but the deeper the cut towards the wall makes me think that I have to get further and further at an angle that puts the exterior sheathing at risk of being carved right through.

4) **Chainsaw** - Kidding...but I'm out of ideas on how best to do this really.

Comment: 5) Hand Saw. Do you even lift bro? Also,why do you want to cut that section out?

Comment: If like in the photo you have side access to the stud, I'd use a multitool with the blade rotated 90 degrees, so you're coming at it from the side of the stud

Comment: Cutting out a section of stud weakens the wall. If this wall is not load-bearing that might be toletable, though it would be better to properly frame around the opening . If it *is* loadbearing, you really want this properly framed -- or you should consider alternatives like drilling holes through the stud rather than removing part of it. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish cutting the stud out. There could be many reasons for wanting to cut out a stud that might be useful for other visitors such as cutting out rotten portions of studs (and replacing them), or cutting out areas for a new door (for non-load bearing walls), or cutting out medicine cabinets. Totally understand the concern of damaging the structure, but there could be many reasons for the desired outcome here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for my [pull saw](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DEWALT-Double-Edge-Pull-Saw-DWHT20216/205436902) or my [oscillating saw/multitool](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ryobi-2-Amp-Corded-Multi-Tool-MT100G/205978358)

You should be able to get most of the way through with the oscillating saw and then finish it by hand with a compact hand saw. I like my compact pull saws to tight spaces like that.

Comment: You can also use the multitool to cut the pesky drywall screws that will likely be attached to the piece of stud that you are removing.

Answer (score 1):

I installed an in-wall spice rack with 60 spice jars. I cut the section of the stud with a circular saw and a chisel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).